# Can't compile simple SDL program with Dev-C++

Tags: c++, sdl

Just before you read just know that i'm not english, so hopefully i won't misspell my writing here.
Anyway. I was trying to compile my first SDL program, so i followed online tutorials to install SDL2 libraries. The code (copied from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjZVOKotohg&list=PLmpc3xvYSk4wDCP5zjt2QQXe8-JGHa4Kt&index=59) *min 13:00*) i used is this  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void){

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        cout << "SDL init failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "SDL init succeeded";
    SDL_Quit();


    return 0;
}
```

The error i get is this

```
C:\Users\raffaele.ciotola\Desktop\Marco & Lory\Lorenzo\Dev-Cpp\SDL2-2.0.12\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.o) In function `main_getcmdline':
71      s:\rs\valve\release\SDL\SDL2-2.0.12-source\src\main\windows\SDL_windows_main.c  undefined reference to `SDL_main'
C:\Users\raffaele.ciotola\Desktop\Marco & Lory\Lorenzo\Dev-Cpp\Programs\SDL_\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
25      C:\Users\raffaele.ciotola\Desktop\Marco & Lory\Lorenzo\Dev-Cpp\Programs\SDL_\Makefile.win   recipe for target 'SDL_.exe' failed
```

I tried running my Dev-Cpp.exe on administrator, since the installation folder is on the desktop, but that didn't solve the problem.

The Makefile (Whatevere it is, i don't have the minimal idea) is this. If needed ¯_(ツ)_/¯.

```
# Project: Progetto3
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.11

CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
OBJ      = SDL_.o
LINKOBJ  = SDL_.o
LIBS     = -L"C:/Users/raffaele.ciotola/Desktop/Marco & Lory/Lorenzo/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Users/raffaele.ciotola/Desktop/Marco & Lory/Lorenzo/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -L"C:/Users/raffaele.ciotola/Desktop/Marco & Lory/Lorenzo/Dev-Cpp/SDL2-2.0.12/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc -mwindows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lopengl32 -lglu32
INCS     = -I"C:/Users/raffaele.ciotola/Desktop/Marco & Lory/Lorenzo/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Users/raffaele.ciotola/Desktop/Marco & Lory/Lorenzo/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Users/raffaele.ciotola/Desktop/Marco & Lory/Lorenzo/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Users/raffaele.ciotola/Desktop/Marco & Lory/Lorenzo/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Users/raffaele.ciotola/Desktop/Marco & Lory/Lorenzo/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Users/raffaele.ciotola/Desktop/Marco & Lory/Lorenzo/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Users/raffaele.ciotola/Desktop/Marco & Lory/Lorenzo/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++" -I"C:/Users/raffaele.ciotola/Desktop/Marco & Lory/Lorenzo/Dev-Cpp/SDL2-2.0.12/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
BIN      = SDL_.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) 
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) 
RM       = rm.exe -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

SDL_.o: SDL_.cpp
    $(CPP) -c SDL_.cpp -o SDL_.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

If you need any other info just ask. Thank You.

Comment: SDL used to require that `main` be defined as `int main(int , char** )`. This may still be a requirement.

Comment: apparently, yes, this is my problem, and @Fibbles 's methos worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL hijacks the `main` function with its own in order to do some initial setup. It then calls whatever you have written as the `main` function. Because it is calling your `main` function it expects it to be defined in a specific way.

Try this and it should resolve the errors you are encountering:

```
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    // whatever
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This made my program work. Thank you.
Just antoher question... as you can see i have put different cout s in my program, but, since i create an SDL window, i don't get to see my text. How can i get the console output from the Dev-Cpp.exe application?

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used SDL under Windows so I can't say why you aren't getting any console output. I'd recommend posting it as a separate question.